# Canaria's song in Qualidea Code?

Tags: qualidea-code

What is the song that Canaria sings in the Qualidea Code anime? It is also called as the song of healing.

Answer (score 1):

It is titled "TIME TO GO", and is track #21 on [the first volume of the OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/60222).